# Couldn't start android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, adt

I am using fedora 17. And Have been using the ADT bundle. But the system couldn't create the virtual machine.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/anshul/LinuxUtilityLab/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get.

Open a terminal and type the following.

```
 apt-get install ia32-libs
```

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html. Check the the link under TroubleShooting linux

Edit

Try the below

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/9556/how-do-i-install-32bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit-fedora/

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/8969/installing-android-sdk-on-64-bit-fedora/

```
sudo yum install libstdc++.i686
sudo yum install ncurses-libs.i686
sudo yum install zlib.i686
```

Comment: I am using fedora sir. Its for ubuntu.

Comment: Give it a try coz i too faced a similar problem and solved it by using the above. The command should work on fedrora also. Give a try and then if the problem is not solved post the same here.

Comment: this happens because your sdk in 32bit and your fedora distribution is 64bit. Try installing the packages in the above it.

Comment: Since there is no ia32-libs package since (k)ubuntu 11.10, I installed the \*32\* versions of the packages listed in the answer, i.e. "lib32stdc++". That solved it on 13.10 Beta 1.

Answer (score 2):

I see two slashes between sdk and tools in the path in your error message, I would start there.

.../sdk//tools/...

Comment: I have just checked the path for the sdk. The path was /home/anshul/LinuxUtilityLab/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk

Answer (score 0):

You do not need install packages any more!

In directory tools, there are many types of `emulator`, while my computer works with `emulator64-arm`! My system is `Linux Mint 16 amd64`! Good luck!

```
./emulator64-arm @yxphone -sdcard yxsd -scale 0.8
```